# How to set source-directories when running elm-reactor

Tags: elm, elm-reactor

How do I specify areas for looking up Module names in `elm-reactor`, current it says

`I cannot find module 'MyModule'.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `elm-package.json` file, using the "source-directories" key. I believe the default is `[ "." ]`, so by default it will look in the same directory as the `elm-package.json` file.

```
{
    "source-directories": [
        "."
    ]
}
```

You can change it to `[ "src" ]` or even add multiple paths, since it's an array.

Comment: so if im running `elm-make` does it always look for a file locally named `elm-package.json`?

Comment: Correct. Several of the elm commands use the `elm-package.json` for info about project, like installed packages and source directory..